# INSERT and detect unique constraint error

Tags: mysql, sql, exception, mariadb

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS devices_used_by_resource (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  sourcesId INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, sourcesId),
  INDEX sourcesIdInx (sourcesId ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX nameSourceUniqueInx (name ASC, sourcesId ASC),
  CONSTRAINT existingSourcesId
    FOREIGN KEY (sourcesId)
    REFERENCES sources (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I wish the following query:

```
INSERT INTO devices_used_by_resource(id,sourcesId,name) VALUES(123,321,'the name');
```

to respond as:

- If id/sourcesId of 123/321 does not exist, insert record.
- If id/sourcesId of 123/321 does exist and name is equal to 'the name', ignore.
- If id/sourcesId of 123/321 does exist and name is not equal to 'the name', throw exception.

`sourcesId` will have been previously validated as existing.

Is this possible, and if so how?

PS.  Is index sourcesIdInx required, and if so why?

Comment: Based on the unique constraint, your second requirement will fail with a database exception. Also, I think you may have your logic reversed in requiring a unique name. I think you should switch ignore and throws between 2 and 3.

Comment: @RossBush  2 shouldn't be an error because nothing changed.  3 should be an error because something changed.  My intent is to then perform an insert in another table which includes `id.devices_used_by_resources` and need to make sure it exists for and hasn't been changed..

Comment: I misread your intent. However, it is not clear. Why don't you add the id field to your nameSourceUniqueInx unique constraint. That way you can be guaranteed that all id/sourceId/name combinations in the table will be unique.

Comment: @RossBush  Because name needs to be unique for a given sourcesId regardless of id value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use that statement as it is. A violation of a unique key will raise an error. You will have to catch that error, either with `insert ignore` (which does not allow you to react to your 3rd condition), or with `on duplicate key`.

You can use an `on duplicate key` that will intentionally throw an error if your conditions are met. Unfortunately, the errormessage will not be directly related to the violation, it will just be "any" exception (an exception that describes your situation does not exist anyway). In the `update`-part, check if the name is different. If it is unchanged, you do nothing ("ignore"), if it is changed, you can set an invalid value to e.g. throw a `not null`-error:

```
INSERT INTO devices_used_by_resource(id,sourcesId,name) 
VALUES(123,321,'the name')
on duplicate key update id = if(name = values(name), id, null);

> 1 row(s) affected

INSERT INTO devices_used_by_resource(id,sourcesId,name) 
VALUES(123,321,'the name')
on duplicate key update id = if(name = values(name), id, null);

> 0 row(s) affected

INSERT INTO devices_used_by_resource(id,sourcesId,name) 
VALUES(123,321,'the name1')
on duplicate key update id = if(name = values(name), id, null);

> Error Code: 1048. Column 'id' cannot be null
```

You have a second unique index on `(name, sourcedId)`, that will also trigger `on duplicate key`. You didn't specifiy what should happen if you insert a row that violates this, so the statement will just ignore it (a violation of `(name, sourcedId)` will not change the name, so no exception is thrown):

```
INSERT INTO devices_used_by_resource(id,sourcesId,name) 
VALUES(1,321,'the name')
on duplicate key update id = if(name = values(name), id, null);

> 0 row(s) affected
```

If you want to throw an exception then too, you can compare all values instead of just the name, so a different `id` will also raise an error:

```
INSERT INTO devices_used_by_resource(id,sourcesId,name) 
VALUES(123,321,'the name1')
on duplicate key update 
id = if(id = values(id) and sourcesId = values(sourcesId) 
        and name = values(name), id, null);

> Error Code: 1048. Column 'id' cannot be null
```

The exception message is obviously not very clear about the error, because it raises an unrelated error. If you just want to catch that exception and know what it actually means, that will be fine. To make it a little more stylish, you could add a trigger that uses `id=null` as an indicator to throw a custom message, e.g.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger trbu_devices_used_by_resource 
  before update on devices_used_by_resource
for each row
begin
  if new.id is null then 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
    SET message_text = 'Inserted duplicate entry with different attributes!';
  end if;
end $$  
delimiter ;
```

It will also throw that error if you use `update devices_used_by_resource set id = null` without an insert, but I guess that does not happen that often, or maybe you can find a message that covers that too - or you do some more complicated communication between the upsert and the trigger, e.g. set the `id` or `sourcesId` to `-812677` and check for that values in the trigger.